# SeekBarPreference showSeekBarValue value not shown properly

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-preferences

I'm trying to use [SeekBarPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/SeekBarPreference) from *android.support.v7.preference* and also I want the current value to be shown. There is an attribute showSeekBarValue that makes this possible. The value is shown but it seems like the `TextView` that holds the value isn't styled properly and part of the value is unfortunately hidden.

[image]

This is my preferences xml:

```
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <SeekBarPreference
        android:key="size"
        android:title="Size"
        android:summary="size of progressBar in dp's"
        android:max="100"
        app:showSeekBarValue="true"
        android:defaultValue="25" />
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

and this is my Preference fragment:

```
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat

class SettingsFragment: PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences)
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The picture is much too big and not even a quarter is needed. Please adjust the image next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the library code and in the layout(preference_widget_seekbar.xml) the height set on the textView is `match_parent` while the height of the parent is `wrap_content`.
Setting the height of textView to `wrap_content` solves the issue.

This is `onViewCreated` of my `SettingsFragment`:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    listView.viewTreeObserver.addOnDrawListener {
        val sizePref = findPreference(getString(R.string.size))

        val prefView: View? = listView.layoutManager.findViewByPosition(sizePref.order)
        prefView?.apply {
            //Here is the fix
            findViewById<TextView>(seekbar_value).apply {
                layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
            }
            //another visual improvement
            findViewById<AppCompatSeekBar>(seekbar).apply {
                (layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
                    gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi check the below url for ur requirement.

https://v4all123.blogspot.com/2017/12/simple-example-of-seekbarpreference-in.html

i think the layout height is fixed i guess. if u use wrap_content hope it should work by doing change in height or the url may help you.

Comment: The blog post is wrong. There is a seekbar preference is android. Check the link in question